# My tv is cutting the edges off my desktop

Tags: resolution

I have a mitsubishi ws 65315 tv, an ATI radeon x1300 graphics card and Ubuntu 12.04.

My problem is that I can't see the edges of the screen, so I can't get to the dash very easily and the whole point of hooking it up to the tv was for hulu and general media.

So my question is, does anyone know how I can either move the axis of the desktop so I can see everything? Or is there any other kind of known problem like this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with my Samsung TV. Use the remote that came with the TV, push the menu button (or options) on the TV, and look for an option that disables "overscan," or sets the display ratio to 16/9. This may be hiding in an advanced section.

Edit: There are a bunch of articles about this -- search for overscan, 1-1 pixel mode, or "pc mode": http://www.engadget.com/2007/08/20/does-your-hdtv-support-1-1-pixel-mapping/

Comment: Thanks for the overscan idea. Annoyingly I found exactly what I needed but don't have the proper remote control, so I don't have all the buttons I need to get into the proper service menus and everything. Thank you again for the help.